# How base and collector has nearly the same majority charge carrier concentration

Tags: transistors, bjt

*Size*: Collector > Emitter > Base

*Doping*: Emitter > Base > Collector

In the *Function* section of this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Function), they have said that Collector & Base have the same concentration of majority charge carriers.

***Doubt:*** If the base is less in size and more doped then the *majority carriers have less place in base*. If the collector is more in size but less doped then *majority carriers have more space in collector*.

***Question:*** *If majority carriers have more space in collector & less space in the base, then how they've nearly the same concentration?* 
[image: BJT three layers with connection]

Comment: I suspect the "concentration" is in carriers per cubic micron, that is, per unit volume.

Comment: It's just a little more complex than your image suggests. See: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brEJZ.jpg).